# How can I create a Facebook page for a company who's name less than 5 characters long?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I would like to know the right procedure for a companies that have **less that 5 characters** to register their page username.

Facebook Pages have this restriction "*Usernames must be at least 5 characters long*" but there are lots with less chars like https://www.facebook.com/ford or https://www.facebook.com/nba

Any clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the brand name and power that the big-hitters like Ford, CNN, NBA etc have, I imagine that you won't be able to create a Page username less than 5 characters.

I would think that because these types of companies are so well known Facebook has given them special dispensation with regards to the [rules and regulations](https://www.facebook.com/help?page=900) on creating usernames for pages.

As such there doesn't seem to an official route via the Facebook site to apply for a page with a username less than 5 characters. Probably because it would no doubt be inundated with requests. I should think the bigger global companies have contact Facebook directly via their PR office or similar.

This of course, is only my opinion and would only be answered 100% correctly by a member of staff from Facebook.

Answer (score 3):

You can try phoning Facebook at 650-543-4800, or emailing them at Marketing@fb.com or at info@fb.com. However, I'm in social media marketing circles and even Facebook page admins of large multinational corporations can't get through to contact Facebook.